# Quickest way to create 300+ rows of 'string' + (row #) + 'string'

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create an Excel sheet for a test mailing list, so that I end up with 300+ rows of:

```
test1@test.com
test2@test.com
test3@test.com
...
test300@test.com
```

How can I quickly generate all of these rows? I don't know Excel that well but I've tried =CONCATENATE('test',A1,'@test.com') thinking that seems right, but that's not a valid formula. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. It was pretty simple, but my syntax was a little off. Here's what I ended up with:

```
=CONCATENATE("test",ROW(),"@test.com")
```

Comment: Yes - or     ="test"&ROW()&"@test.com"

Comment: That seems much simpler and obvious. Thanks!